# Getting rid of the extra header row for HTML styling of Pandas multi-index DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

This pandas code:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame([[0,0,1,2,3],[0,1,3,4,5],[1,0,4,5,6],[1,1,5,6,7]],
            columns=['A','B','X','Y','Z'])
df.set_index(['A','B'], inplace=True)
df
```

displays as follows in IPython Notebook:

[image]

Note that there are two header rows, to distinguish the index columns from the data columns.

Is there any way to get these to show in only one header row?

Comment: grrr, I had this feeling of deja vu, knew I'd asked this before but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

just use, columns names also in `set_index`:

```
df.set_index(['A','B','X','Y','Z'], inplace=True)
df
```

[image]

Comment: I don't want to do that. Note that it puts all data values in bold (`<th>` cells rather than `<td>`)